# Is it possible to set an override to tooltip and set it to a method with parameters

Tags: c#, tooltip

I want to know if it possible to set a `ToolTip` to a method with parameters to additionally describe what the method is doing and what parameters is it using, so that when it is used by another developer be will informed of the method purpose and usage properly, or by adding additional requirement like converting values to be used as parameters.

Like when converting to Int32 like in this screen shot:

[image]

What I want is to find out if it possible to do the same thing for custom methods, where we can tell the developer who is using the method what the method is doing and if he need to cast any parameters and if there is an overloading for the method, by may be setting a `tooltip` to the method somehow, while I know that `tooltips` can be only set to controls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're describing [XML documentation comments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/z04awywx.aspx).  These will all show up in the intellisense tooltips:

```
/// <summary>
/// Documentation that describes the interface goes here.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// Details about the interface go here.
/// </remarks>
interface TestInterface
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Documentation that describes the method goes here.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="n">
    /// Parameter n requires an integer argument.
    /// </param>
    /// <returns>
    /// The method returns an integer.
    /// </returns>
    int InterfaceMethod(int n);
}
```

Comment: That is it then a simple documentation will do. Thanks.